# How to split Spring Conditional configuration?

Tags: java, spring, configuration, conditional-statements

My application uses its own Spring configuration `Condition` to provide beans according to setup, but because of volumes, I expect to split long `@Configuration` instead of adding `@Conditional` to tens of beans.

At the moment, my main security configuration looks like

```
@Configuration @EnableOAuth2Client @EnableWebSecurity
@Import(OptionalAuthenticationConfiguration.class)
public class WebshopSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired(required = false)
    private OptionalAuthenticationConfiguration auth;
```

And here is conditional configuration

```
@Configuration
@Conditional(MyCondition.class)
public class OptionalAuthenticationConfiguration {
[...]
```

Because of `@Conditional` on optional configuration, `@Import` annotation fails with

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'webshopSecurityConfig': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is 
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private OptionalAuthenticationConfiguration
WebshopSecurityConfig.auth; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException:
No qualifying bean of type [OptionalAuthenticationConfiguration] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency.
Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
```

Even if bean attribute `WebshopSecurityConfig.auth` has `required = false`.

Is there a way to achieve such conditional configuration splitting in Spring?

Comment: `OptionalAuthenticationConfiguration` is a configuration why are you autowiring it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I described in this question is expected to work... as far as "MyCondition" properly returns true, and my trouble was there.

Project context was far more complex than shown here: "OptionalAuthenticationConfiguration" is in fact a Spring Security SAML setup which expects many beans from "WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter".

As a result, my code ended with circular "@Import" between these two configurations. I had to move 5 beans from "OptionalAuthenticationConfiguration" to "WebshopSecurityConfig" and make each of them "@Conditional".

Answer (score 2):

Make `OptionalAuthenticationConfiguration` an interface with two implementations.

An actual implementation with `@Conditional(MyCondition.class)` and an empty implementation with `@ConditionalOnMissingBean`.

This way when `MyCondition` doesn't allow the configuration to be created, it will get replaced by a placeholder empty implementation.